# CRUD Operations in Sharepoint Online using JavaScript on external site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, javascript

I am currently trying to create a List Item in my SharePoint 2013 online environment using JavaScript Code on an external Website and domain.
Basically I have no idea where to start and I am not sure if its even possible because of the cross domain problem.

I know it's a little to much to ask but i would be grateful if you could give me a detailed answer or link me to a similar solution, because i can't seem to find any.

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only through AZURE **OR** an APP or ADD-IN can you access content in SP using the REST api (and ADAL)

Most links in the other answer are about making REST calls **within** the same domain.

I have a similar open question:
[Is Visual Studio required to built a Front End to write (REST) data into a SharePoint Online list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/152756/is-visual-studio-required-to-built-a-front-end-to-write-rest-data-into-a-share)

Comment: *Where did that previous comment mentioning [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj945118.aspx#Overview) go??* You are correct, that functionaly opens the door to your OnPrem environment.  You can even do that without a high trust app/add-in if you can develop your own middle tier

Comment: When did the name change from app to add in occur?

Comment: Couple of weeks ago, Yammer is filled with complaints  by SharePoint MVPs who can't handle the new "Agile" Microsoft

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to access sharepoint data from outside of sharepoint, (ie in a .net application / android app etc), then you need to consume the client object model or the web service exposed by sharepoint.

This [Discussion](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79803/how-to-authenticate-user-in-sharepoint-online-using-javascript) has a pretty detailed explanation towards using `authentication.asmx` to get a token that can be used for intearaction with sharepoint. You would need to pass credentials in order to get the token.

If you are looking to leverage the `CSOM`, sharepoint client side API, then you need to add, `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll` and then proceed to initialize a context with `SharePointOnlineCredentails` for o365 enviornment, or `NetworkCredentials` for sharepoint On Premise enviorment.

You should go through links mentioned by Kaushal in order to get a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by multiple ways

i) JSOM

ii) REST API

Basically i choose REST API to remotely access SharePoint Office2013 Online.

Go through Links

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142380.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/HowTo/examples-of-office-365-unified-api-calls

https://codeplayandlearn.wordpress.com/2015/07/07/53/