# Execute crud operations using rest api outside SharePoint by .NET

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, api

I need to do CRUD operations on SharePoint online lists (intranet) using REST api from a standalone Asp.Net application which is hosted completely outside office 365 (on on-premise).

I know that it is almost impossible using JavaScript, but my question is about using c#. 
Do I need to use username and password in the code? Or I have to solve the permission using OAuth or another technology?

Comment: Look into ADAL, for PHP and Phython see https://github.com/vgrem?tab=repositories

Answer (score 2):

If  you want to perform CRUD operation on SharePoint Online lists, for that you can use C# code with console app or window app or else create web application.

The same requirement i was also having. So i used C# console application.

And yes you need to authenticate first, and for authentication you can use Username and Password into the code itself which will encrypt your credentials before sending over network. I used this mechanism for authentication.

For more details regarding Authentication you can refer this thread [Authenticating client with office 365/SharePoint online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20950628/authenticating-client-with-office-365-sharepoint-online)

You can create the Provider Hosted App and using this you can perform CRUD operation on SharePoint Web Hosted list.

For getting started with SharePoint Provider Hosted App you can go through [Get started creating provider-hosted SharePoint Add-ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142381.aspx)

Let me know if i missed something in the answer.

If you want create a list item from outside the SharePoint Environment then you can use following code.

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("your sharepoint online site url"))
            {
                SecureString passWord = new SecureString();

                foreach (char c in "your password".ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);

                clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("your username", passWord);

                Web web = clientContext.Web;

                clientContext.Load(web);

                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                var myList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("your list name");
                ListItemCreationInformation listItemCreate = new ListItemCreationInformation();
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem newItem = myList.AddItem(listItemCreate);
                newItem["Title"] = "Item added by Job at " + DateTime.Now;
                newItem.Update();
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                Console.WriteLine(web.Title);


                Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

It worked for me. The above code is just console application. You can convert it into GUI also.

And for reference purpose you can refer this link [Call O365 using CSOM with a Console Application](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2014/02/23/call-o365-using-csom-with-a-console-application/)

Let me know if you face any issue in running above code.

If you want to create an list item using REST API Service call then please refer this discussion [CRUD Operations in Sharepoint Online using JavaScript on external site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/154020/crud-operations-in-sharepoint-online-using-javascript-on-external-site)

Comment: Thank you Aakash, No I don't want to create Provider hosted app. Acctually it is about one of our partners which have a asp.net application. They want to change items inside a list of our SharePoint online directly from their web application. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Yes, it uses CSOM. I was wondering if it is possible do the same you wrote but using SPO REST API, not csom?

Comment: please check this discussion once http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/154020/crud-operations-in-sharepoint-online-using-javascript-on-external-site

Comment: So according to your link (the discussion thread), it is impossible to call sharepoint online api from a standalone application.

Comment: Its not like that @Medes. That link is just for information. Actuallly i am not confident hence i didn't added much description. Will update my answer again with valid code if thing is possible. :-)

Comment: if your application and sharepoint is not in the same domain then you cannot use REST service to update your SharePoint data until you don't use SharePoint Apps. I think you must go with this thread also, it have much more deep explanation about what you are trying to do  http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/134300/updating-sharepoint-item-using-rest-api-from-outside-of-sharepoint

Comment: Thank you Aakash, I have one thought, what about creating a usual asp.net mvc and add a public web api controller and then using your code inside the controller. Is it possible? so we are going to have an api that our customer can consume.